# Row number for first action

Tags: impala, row-number

I have a table with user ids and action logs. And i would like to get the following result:

```
+---------+------------+---------+
| user_id | action_id | row_num |
+---------+------------+---------+
| id1     | action 1   |       1 |
| id1     | action 1   |       2 |
| id1     | action 2   |       1 |
| id1     | action 3   |       1 |
| id2     | action 1   |       1 |
| id2     | action 2   |       1 |
| id2     | action 3   |       1 |
| id2     | action 3   |       2 |
| id2     | action 3   |       3 |
+---------+------------+---------+
```

I am pretty sure I need to use ROW_NUMBER() function, and trying to achieve this by executing the following code:

```
select user_id,
action_id,
row_number() over (partition by action_id order by user_id desc) as rn
from table
```

But it seems like I am missing something. Would you please help me?
I am using Impala SQL syntax.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `action_id` instead in `order by` clause:

```
select user_id, action_id,
       row_number() over (partition by user_id, action_id order by action_id) as rn
from table t;
```

Second, you haven't specify the `action_id` in *partition* clause

Comment: Thanks a lot! Vasmi suggested the same above

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Use

```
row_number() over (partition by user_id,action_id order by action_id) as rn
```